# How to create a "householdID" for rows with shared "customerID" and "spouseID"?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a "household ID" for all couples who appear in a larger dataframe (about 250,000 rows). Each individual has a "customerID" and "spouseID" value. If a customerID is married, their spouse's ID appears in the "spouseID" column. If they are not married, the spouseID field is empty. Each member of a married couple will appear on its own row, resulting in the need for a common "householdID" that a couple shares.

What is the best way to and add a unique householdID that duplicates for couples? A small example of the original data would be:

```
> df <- data.frame(prospectID=as.numeric(c(1:10)),
+                  spouseID=as.numeric(c(2,1,"",5,4,"","","",10,9)))
> df
   prospectID spouseID
1           1        2
2           2        1
3           3       NA
4           4        5
5           5        4
6           6       NA
7           7       NA
8           8       NA
9           9       10
10         10        9
```

A simple example of what I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
   prospectID spouseID householdID
1           1        2           1
2           2        1           1
3           3       NA           2
4           4        5           3
5           5        4           3
6           6       NA           4
7           7       NA           5
8           8       NA           6
9           9       10           7
10         10        9           7
```

Comment: Create new ID columns that are sorted - say `ID1` and `ID2` where `ID1` is always the lower number of the two IDs. Then you can assign household IDs based on `ID1` (or, if households change over time, you could assign it based on the concatenation of ID1 and ID2).

Comment: If you need help implementing, please edit your question to include data in a copy/pasteable format---I can't test/debug/demonstrate a solution on a picture of data. The nicest (and easiest) way to share data is with `dput`. `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` will give a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of data. (Of course, choose a suitable subset - we may not need all the columns, and maybe rows other than the first 10 are more illustrative.)

Comment: Added example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it is to create an extra string variable that is the sum-product of the 2 IDs of prospect and spouse. For a single customer that would be Prospect_ID-0 e.g., 201-0. For the 1st couple that would be 251-15150. For each couple this value would be unique yet any couple would get the same value. Then you can just assign an household ID field for sum-product.

Comment: This is a fantastic and simple solution. It works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: The code was a simple `df = df %>% mutate(householdID = (prospectID+spouseID)-(prospectID*spouseID))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pmin`/`pmax` to sort the two columns and create a new `ID` variable based on those two columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(col1 = pmin(prospectID, spouseID), 
        col2 = pmax(prospectID, spouseID)) %>%
  mutate(household_ID = group_indices(., col1, col2))
```

Or another option :

```
df %>%
  mutate(grp = paste(pmin(prospectID, spouseID), pmax(prospectID, spouseID)), 
         household_ID = match(grp, unique(grp)))

#   prospectID spouseID  grp household_ID
#1           1        2  1 2            1
#2           2        1  1 2            1
#3           3        0  0 3            2
#4           4        5  4 5            3
#5           5        4  4 5            3
#6           6        0  0 6            4
#7           7        0  0 7            5
#8           8        0  0 8            6
#9           9       10 9 10            7
#10         10        9 9 10            7
```

---

When you read the data in R, replace the blank values with 0 or any other number for `pmin` and `pmax` to work.

```
df[df == ''] <- 0
df <- type.convert(df)
```

Comment: @mikerobru It does work fine for me. The column names were different in your screenshot and dataframe example though. I have updated the answer with the output that I am getting. Don't forget to run `df[df == ''] <- 0` and `df <- type.convert(df)` first.

Comment: Replacing the missing values with df[is.na(df)] <- 0 was the key, and it works great. Thanks for taking the time to relpy. @TrangVu has an easy math-based way to go about it as well.

Comment: In your example, you have shown missing value as empty string i.e `""` hence, I used `df[df == ''] <- 0`, If you have missing values as `NA` then yes, you need to do `df[is.na(df)] <- 0 `