# How to create a shared householdID for spouses by referencing two separate character IDs

Tags: r

This quesiton is similar to my previous question ([How to create a "householdID" for rows with shared "customerID" and "spouseID"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671896/how-to-create-a-householdid-for-rows-with-shared-customerid-and-spouseid)), although this version deals with a rats-nest mix of character and numeric strings instead of simply numeric IDs. I'm trying to create a "household ID" for all couples who appear in a larger dataframe. In short, each individual has a "customerID" and "spouseID". If a customerID is married, their spouse's ID appears in the "spouseID" column. If they are not married, the spouseID field is empty. Each member of a married couple will appear on its own row, resulting in the need for a common "householdID" that a couple shares.

What is the best way to and add a unique householdID that duplicates for couples? A small and over-simplified example of the original data is as follows. Note that the original IDs are far more complex, with varying lengths and patters of numbers and characters.

```
df <- data.frame(
  prospectID=as.character(c("G1339jf", "6dhd54G1", "Cf14c", "Bvmkm1", "kda-1qati", "pwn9enr", "wj44v04t4t", "D15", "dkfs044nng", "v949s")),
  spouseID=as.character(  c( "",      "wj44v04t4t", "",      "pwn9enr",     "",     "Bvmkm1", "6dhd54G1",     "", "v949s", "dkfs044nng")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df
   prospectID   spouseID
1     G1339jf           
2    6dhd54G1 wj44v04t4t
3       Cf14c           
4      Bvmkm1    pwn9enr
5   kda-1qati           
6     pwn9enr     Bvmkm1
7  wj44v04t4t   6dhd54G1
8         D15           
9  dkfs044nng      v949s
10      v949s dkfs044nng
```

An example of my desired result is as follows:

```
> df
   prospectID   spouseID HouseholdID
1     G1339jf                      1
2    6dhd54G1 wj44v04t4t           2
3       Cf14c                      3
4      Bvmkm1    pwn9enr           4
5   kda-1qati                      5
6     pwn9enr     Bvmkm1           4
7  wj44v04t4t   6dhd54G1           2
8         D15                      6
9  dkfs044nng      v949s           7
10      v949s dkfs044nng           7
```

Comment: Just to reiterate.....  The solution must treat the ID as a whole, not as parts of the whole, because these real IDs are complex, random, comprised of both letters and numbers, with varying length (such as "F92nS93n49f7f6qm1G", "6ns96f00G23I"....etc.).

Comment: Edited the solution. Now works with completely random strings

Comment: The sum-product answer from your previous question won't work, but the `pmin`/`pmax` solution works whether the IDs are numeric or alphanumeric. One of the IDs is alphabetically first, the other is alphabetically second.  Ronak's code should work just fine. Sorting alphabetically once will be much more efficient then repeated `grep`ing.

Comment: @GregorThomas - You're right! that does work!!  Thank you for the re-direct.

Answer (score 0):

This is an edited solution due to comments made by OP.

Illustrative data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  prospectID=as.character(c("A1jljljljl344asbvc", "A2&%$ll@@fffh", "B1665453sskn:;", "B2gavQWEΩΩø⁄", "C1", "D1", "E1#+'&%", "E255646321", "F1", "G1")),
  spouseID=as.character(c("A2&%$ll@@fffh", "A1jljljljl344asöbvc", "B2gavQWEΩΩø⁄", "B1665453sskn:;_", "", "", "E255646321", "E1#+'&%", "", "")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

First define a pattern to match:

```
patt <- paste(df$prospectID, df$spouseID, sep = "|")
```

Second, define a `for` loop; here, a little editing is necessary for the first and the last value. Maybe others can improve on this part:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$HousholdID[1] <- 1
  df$HousholdID[i] <- ifelse(grepl(patt[i], df$prospectID[i+1]), 1, 0)
  df$HousholdID[10] <- 1
}
```

The final step is to run `cumsum`:

```
df$HousholdID <- cumsum(df$HousholdID)
```

The result:

```
df
           prospectID            spouseID HousholdID
1  A1jljljljl344asbvc       A2&%$ll@@fffh          1
2       A2&%$ll@@fffh A1jljljljl344asöbvc          1
3      B1665453sskn:;        B2gavQWEΩΩø⁄          2
4        B2gavQWEΩΩø⁄     B1665453sskn:;_          2
5                  C1                              3
6                  D1                              4
7             E1#+'&%          E255646321          5
8          E255646321             E1#+'&%          5
9                  F1                              6
10                 G1                              7
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, although perhaps my quesiton wasn't clear enough in that these are simplified examples of complex, random IDs comprised of both letters and numbers wtih varying length (such as "F92nS93n49f7f6qm1G", "6ns96f00G23I"....etc.). The solution must treat the ID as a whole, not as parts of the whole.

Comment: Okay, always a good idea not to oversimplify matters when asking a question on SO. Is there anything the values in `prospectID` and `spouseID`have in common?

Comment: Nope. No patterns. They are essentially a randomly generated unique key.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. You're correct in that my example may be too simple, as this solution only works when the rows are aligned with the spouses next to each other. In reality, they would appear in any order among roughly 500K rows (almost guaranteeing they wouldn't be next to each other. I will update the question's example df to clarify this point.